# The quaternion moat problem

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, open-problems, quaternions, quaternionic-geometry

> "One cannot walk to infinity on the real line if one uses steps of bounded
> length and steps on the prime numbers.  This is simply
> a restatement of the classic result that there are arbitrarily
> large gaps in the primes."

So begins the paper by
Gethner, Wagon, and Wick,
["A Stroll Through the Gaussian Primes"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2589708)
(*American Mathematical Monthly*
**105**(4): 327-337 (1998).)
They explain that it is unknown if one can walk to infinity on the Gaussian primes
with steps of bounded length.
Paul Erdős was reported to have conjectured this is possible
("A conjecture of Paul Erdős concerning Gaussian primes."
*Math. Comp* **24**: 221-223 (1970);
[PDF](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1970-24-109/S0025-5718-1970-0256976-8/S0025-5718-1970-0256976-8.pdf)).
Later Erdős is reported to have conjectured the opposite:
that no such walk-to-$\infty$ is possible [GWW98, p.327].
This has become known as the *Gaussian moat problem*, apparently still unresolved.

My question is:

> Is there an analogous *quaternion moat problem*?
> Is it solved? open? Is it easier or harder than the Gaussian moat problem?

Define a nonzero quaternion $q = a + bi + cj + dk$ as *prime* iff (a) it is a [Hurwitz quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_quaternion) (all components integer, or all components half-integer)
and (b) its norm $a^2 + b^2 +c^2 + d^2$ is prime.
(Part (b) is a consequence of the inability to factor $q$; see, e.g.,
Theorem 15 in *"A proof of Lagrange's four square theorem using quaternion algebras."
Drew Stokesbary, 2007; [PDF](http://www.duke.edu/%7Eds53/QuaternionAlgebra.pdf), DOI: [10.2139/ssrn.2396123](https://doi.org/10.2139/ssrn.2396123)).

> Can one "walk-to-$\infty$" on the quaternion primes using steps of bounded length?

Perhaps relevant here is
[Lagrange's four-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem), which states
that any natural number can be represented as the sum of four squares.

I ask this question in relative naïveté, and appreciate being enlightened.

Comment: You're using the word "quaternion" loosely, as if "real number" meant "integer".  You intended to impose some kind of integrality constraint on the coefficients of your quaternions. Do you mean to focus on the quaternions with integral coefficients or the larger ring that allows all coefficients to be halves of odd integers too? Your discussion of the meaning of prime is also vague, as you don't make clear whether the properties you describe are definitions or genuine results (and for which kind of integral quaternion)?

Comment: @KConrad: Points well-taken! I apologize for my unfamiliarity with the intricacies of the topic. I meant the prime Hurwitz quaternions: components all integers or all half-integers. But more broadly I am interested in any reasonable analog of the Gaussian moat problem generalized to quaternions.

Comment: @unknowngoogle: Let us take the definition of a quaternion prime as: its norm is a prime. I was only attempting to indicate from where that definition derives. 

Comment: I don't think you can avoid the Hurwitz restriction, e.g., consider 4+(2i+2j+k)/3 which has norm 17.

Comment: @François: Excellent point!  But couldn't one then consider
$(4, \frac{2i}{3}, \frac{2j}{3}, \frac{k}{3})$ a prime, in some sense
of "prime"?

Comment: I suspect (but I haven't checked) that what you obtain with the prime norm criterion is probably dense everywhere and the problem becomes trivial.

Comment: @François: Ah! I see your point...

Comment: a crazy idea: the unit quaternion sphere has some interesting folations that the unit complex numbers don't have. Unless you force some sort of integrality, given a 'prime' with integrality condition, you probably get a _lot_ of 'primes' without the integrality condition. But this is just a crazy stab, and probably nothing.

Comment: @David: Intriguing speculation! Connected with François's point, it may be that one can "walk-to-$\infty$" on the quaternion primes...?

Comment: Joseph, please edit your question so you give a definite context there to what your terms mean (e.g., refer to a nonzero Hurwitz quaternion, not just a nonzero quaternion) and at the end you can say you're interested in any other quaternionic setting where there's a Gaussian moat problem too if the Hurwitz setting is too restrictive.

Comment: Calling an arbitrary quaternion prime when its norm is a prime number is a lousy idea: you ought to fix a definite ring of interest like the Hurwitz quaternions to give the term a meaning (and the fact that primality is equivalent to the norm being prime should be a *theorem*, not a definition).

Comment: One could ditch the quaternions and just ask whether it's possible to walk to infinity on points of prime squared-length in ${\bf Z}^4$, no? I mean, it's not the same question, but it might be just as interesting. 

Comment: @Joseph - thank you! Maybe the foliations are not even needed. But I agree with KConrad: one should fix a ring of quarternions and work with that. @Gerry - now that _is_ an interesting alternative.

Comment: Apologies to all for the lack of clarity. I've narrowed the question to Hurwitz quaternions, my original intent, although it is now clear there are related questions one could ask as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Having an infinite walk of bounded step length in the quaternions (or in $\mathbb Z^k$ in Gerry's version), gives us a sequence of primes $p_1,p_2\dots$ with $p_{k+1}-p_k=O(\sqrt{p_k})$. However the best unconditional result we have so far on prime gaps is $O(p_k^{0.525})$ by Baker, Harman and Pintz. So these problems are all open in general.

That said the heuristics that work for Gaussian primes can almost always be translated to a more general setting. One famous article on the topic is Vardi's paper ["Prime percolation"](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/experimental-mathematics/volume-7/issue-3/Prime-percolation/em/1047674208.full). There it is mentioned that the percolation model can be extended to the general case of primes represented by quadratic forms, quaternion primes etc. (where one can make the same predictions), though this is not written anywhere.

Comment: Here is the [BHP] paper to which you refer:
"The Difference Between Consecutive Primes, II." Proceedings of the London Mathematical Society (2001), 83: 532-562. http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=87509

Comment: What was not at first clear to me was your key observation that $p_{k+1}-p_k = O( p_k^{0.5} )$.  It is a nice insight---very clever!  Thanks!